# Determine window position on macOS using swift (or Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I am looking for a way to determine the position and dimension of a window that is not part of my application in macOS using Swift (prefered) or Objective-C to program an overlay/hud.
Is it possible to read a list of all processes and start from there or is there something similar to the getWindowHandle() function in the Windows api?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo):

```
import CoreGraphics 

if let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo([.optionAll], kCGNullWindowID) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    for window in windowList {
        let number = window[kCGWindowNumber as String]!
        let bounds = CGRect(dictionaryRepresentation: window[kCGWindowBounds as String] as! CFDictionary)!
        
        let name = window[kCGWindowName as String] as? String ?? ""
        print("number = \(number), name = \(name), bounds = \(bounds)")
    }
} else {
    print("Can't get window list")
}
```

The function returns an array of `CFDictionary`, which the code above bridged into `[String: AnyObject]` for easy working in Swift. Here are [required](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/quartz_window_services/required_window_list_keys) and [optional](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/quartz_window_services/optional_window_list_keys) keys for the dictionaries. The keys are all defined as `CFString` you must bridge them into `String`.